# Textarea to refresh using jQuery/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, refresh, textarea

OK so let's say I have a textarea on the top of my browser and a text input box on the bottom. I want to connect a MySQL database and also whatever I type in the input box to appear in the text area. Sorta like a text RPG...

I know PHP, MySQL, good AJAX, and little jQuery. I just want to know how this is achieved. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know AJAX? (I must ask this or else I'm going to make foolish assumptions)

Comment: Yes I know AJAX... but I am not master at it.

Comment: i still feel the question is not very clear. Why do you want to connect to mysql? to store whatever you type in input box in db and then also show in textarea. If you simply want to show whatever you type in textbox in textarea this can be done thorugh simple js.But if you want to involve database it will need ajax then

Comment: Well to load profiles and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (the code below sends input text to php script which connects to database, does whatever you want it to do and prints a text to be displayed in text area) :

```
$("#update_btn").click(function() {
    var txt = $.ajax({
    url: 'your_file.php',
    async: true, // or false, depends on your needs
    type:'POST',
    data:({new_text:$('#input_box_1').val()})
     }).responseText;

     $('#txt_area_1').val(txt);
    });
```

To access `new_text` variable in php script, use `$new_text = $_POST["new_text"]`